# Stdout & Stderr redirection using variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, stdout, stderr

I am trying to create 2 variables in my script to redirect error & output to file and display only the errors in the screen and other variable to to display only output in the screen. When i put it as a variable its not working. Variable is coming empty. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp="`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`"
displayonlyerror="2>&1 >> /tmp/postinstall_output_$timestamp.log | tee -a /tmp/postinstall_output_$timestamp.log"
displayoutput="2>&1 |tee -a /tmp/postinstall_output_$timestamp.log"

echo "No screen session found" $displayoutput
ech "No screen session found" $displayerror
```

Comment: Then whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like that, shell parses redirections before performing expansions on other tokens. Instead, define `displayonlyerror` and `displayoutput` as functions like (`file` is the log file name, you change it):

```
displayonlyerror() {
    "$@" 2>&1 >>file | tee -a file
}

displayoutput() {
    "$@" 2>&1 | tee -a file
}
```

and use them like:

```
displayoutput cmd args
displayonlyerror cmd args
```

Comment: I already have a function called color to highlight the errors when executing command. Something like below is used to execute before.

**`color()(set -o pipefail;"$@" 2>&1>&3|sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,'>&2)3>&1`**
 
`color command1 2>&1 |tee -a /tmp/postinstall_output_$timestamp.log`
since we created 2 more functions to store the stderr and stdout how do we call now? Is there a way to call 2 functions at a time in one liner?

Comment: Have you tried `displayoutput color cmd args` or alike?

Comment: It worked. I was trying the opposite way like color displayoutput cmd... Thanks so much :-)